# Offline wiki-like authoring tool

Tags: wiki, help-authoring

Does anyone know if there is a help authoring tool out there that can produce help documentation for a software product that looks like a wiki? We are currently using the [Confluence](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence) wiki engine, which is absolutely brilliant and we were wondering if there is anything like that but without the need for an Apache server. Something stand-alone that can give our users the help documentation they need. We have used help authoring tools and they all seem so clunky compared to a wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Wiki on a Stick](http://stickwiki.sourceforge.net/).
Its a single `.html` file written in `Javascript/html` and saves the changes onto itself. 
You don't even need Apache. *Awesome tool!*

Answer (score 1):

How about [Juli](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jjjuli/)?  It generates static HTML so you can browse documents by browser only.

It is used for:

- Juli documentation itself.
- [Edgar](http://jjedgar.sourceforge.net/en/) project documentation (another my OSS project).
- My personal wiki/blog.  I'll show later since new users can only post two links(stackoverflow limitation)